# Как взять информацию з канала в телеграм если бота там нету

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Хочу сделать бота, который будет искать сообщения с ключевыми словами в разных ТГ каналах. Можно как то сделать так, что бы он мне отправлял инфу без того что бы добавлять его в этот канал? На данный момент использую библиотеку `aoigram` для `Python`
Спасибо!

Comment: Код не нужно, просто скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли такая возможность в этой библиотеке, или какую надо использовать.

Comment: Вам нужно написать своего клиента используя tdlib. В гугле ищите по слову `юзербот`

Comment: @Nick, понял спасибо!